# Flex Mobile - List - Getting noticed when the list is scrolled within an item renderer

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, itemrenderer

I have an itemRenderer which changes its graphics when it is clicked.
When the list gets scrolled again or another itemrenderer is clicked I want to restore the graphics.

But how can I notice inside an ItemRenderer that the list got scrolled?

Best regrads

Chris

Comment: Short answer:  You don't.  Instead of changing a graphic in a `click` event listener, set a property on the data source.  Then set up your `Image` object to display a different graphic based on that property in the underlying data.

Comment: To access List, you could use the `owner` property of the item renderer...

Comment: Got a good solution for my case...

parent.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, parentScrolledHandler);

and

private function parentScrolledHandler(event:PropertyChangeEvent):void
  {
   if(event.property == "verticalScrollPosition")...

Answer (score 0):

You can use property change event of your list. In my case i am using same and it works perfect.

```
lstPost.scroller.viewport.addEventListener( PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, propertyChangeHandler);

protected function propertyChangeHandler( event : PropertyChangeEvent ) : void 
{
    if ( event.property == "verticalScrollPosition" ) 
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```